# C# WPF App doesnt show form when launched by windows service created with topshelf

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, worker, topshelf

I have:

1. Simple WPF app, with 1 window created by Visual studio
2. Windows service (created with topshelf) that starts that app

If I start app manually, it appears in task manager and shows form as it should.

But when it is started by windows service, app appears in task manager, but form isnt shown. What should it the reason?

App launch code in win service

```
                    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.FileName = _app.MainAppDirectory;
                startInfo.Arguments = "";
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
```

Comment: Why `System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`? Also: did you consider that there may be no interactive session at all at this point in time?

Comment: A first, naive thing to do would be to check whether the user that the win service is running from is your user.

Comment: Changed to ProcessWindowStyle.Normal, no effect

Comment: Service runs from System user, not mine. Thus the app is also running under System user. Hmmm, possibly this is why i cant see output. I should run service from my account probably, not system.

Comment: Managed to run service from my local user, not system. Thus, app was also running from local user, but no effect -- app still doesnt show windows

Comment: Services have no ui, by fundamental design. I have seen a worker process that starts up a sta thread for wpf. As I recall it was still rather iffy. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The purpose of the service is to wakeup the core application in case of system reboot, or core app crash, or some closure by occasion

Comment: Tried to run one wpf app from another, works fine, UI is shown

Comment: Wpf - has ui. Services - do not have ui and cannot show ui.

Comment: Andy, pls tell, why WPF cant show UI if launched from service ? Any way to fix it?

Comment: I agree /w the answers. I happened to find this article to consider https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1159908/Yes-I-Know-But-I-Still-Want-a-GUI-for-my-Windows-S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it. `Windows services` are not running under `current user` session. When you login to your Windows, you will get an active session including (Desktop, Environment variables, ..) and whenever you run an application (like a Simple `WindowsForm` or `WPF`, ...) it will runs under your active session. You can open up the `Task manager` and navigate to `Detail` tab to see information about the user who ran each Process (Check this for the `WPF` app when it's ran by your windows service).

You can type `Services` on the `Start menu` and open up `Services` window and find your installed service. You can check a column named `Log on As` there. It's the user account who runs your `Windows service` (it might be `Local System` or `Local Service`).

**It's an interesting fact,** you can write an application who runs even with no logged-in user.

I had the same task, 5 years ago, I tried to steal users session. Using `Impersonation` you are able to steal user token and run your application as an specific user. But still you are not able to see your Application on the desktop.

Look for a different project type to fill your requirements. maybe mark your application as an startup app and hide it's `Forms` from the user.

Comment: You seem to be right. My initial approach to this task was incorrect - its clear when Im asking a simple question - what app would do if no user logged in. Will move business logic to a service, and attach WPF as a viewer/launcher, that is started by user when its needed.

Comment: But here I have another challenge - these 2 apps have to communicate with each other.

Comment: You can write a `Web Api` to work with your `WPF` application. This `WebApi` can could be hosted on a `Windows Service` also. It's a simple kind of `Inter-process communication`.

Comment: I implemented it via named pipes. 2-way inter-process communication. At this moment dont need web-api. but thanks for idea.

Answer (score 0):

Windows services run in [session 0](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ba-p/372361), which isolates services from user applications. This quote from the article gives more details on why they separated user applications from session 0.

> In Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, and earlier versions of the Windows operating system, all services run in the same session as the first user who logs on to the console.  This session is called Session 0. Running services and user applications together in Session 0 poses a security risk because services run at elevated privilege and therefore are targets for malicious agents who are looking for a means to elevate their own privilege level.

There used to be a means to do what you are trying to do by making a [interactive service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services) but the first important section in that document states.

> Services cannot directly interact with a user as of Windows Vista. Therefore, the techniques mentioned in the section titled Using an Interactive Service should not be used in new code.

As far as I know, the checkbox is still there to make a service interactive but is only there for compatibility with installers that might have set it or read it.

[image]

That image is from my Windows 10 machine so the option to turn it on is there but like I said, I am under the impression it does nothing other than prevent applications which attempted to set it from breaking.

Typically the way I have seen applications work around this limitation is by writing a corresponding desktop app that is installed to launch at start and then uses some form of inter-process communication, like a socket to communicate with the app.

Comment: Thanks! Tried that checkbox, doesnt work